# Display a filtered result from ManyToMany through model in Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

This is my models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    forename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.surname, self.forename)

class PersonRole(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        ("Principal investigator", "Principal investigator"),
        [etc...]
    ]
    title = models.CharField(choices=TITLE_CHOICES, max_length=9)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {} as {}.'.format(self.project, self.person, self.person_role)

class Project(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=PersonRole)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_PI(self, obj):
        return [p.person for p in self.person.all()] #I'll then need to filter where person_role is 'Principal investigator', which should be the easy bit.
```

In my Admin back-end I'd like to display the person (principal investigator) in the main table:

```
class ProjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

    list_filter = [PersonFilter, FunderFilter]
    list_display = ("title", "get_PI")
    ordering = ('title',)
```

What I want: display the person with the role 'Principal investigator' in the Projects table in the Admin.

You can see that I created my `get_PI()` in my `models.py` and references in my `list_display`. I'm getting `Project.get_PI() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you have obj as function argument if you are not using it?

Comment: @iklinac because I'm a genius. Thanks for pointing that out! OK, so `def get_PI(self): return [p for p in self.person.all()]` now gives me something. Now I have to filter. Thanks!

Comment: `person.self`? `self.person` makes sense, `person.self` makes no sense, since a `Person` object has no `self` attribute.

Comment: I solved with just `p`, thanks. Anyway, this is my attempt at filtering: `return [p for p in self.person.filter(PersonRole.person_role__contains="Principal investigator")]`. I get `Unsupported lookup 'contains' for ManyToOneRel or join on the field not permitted.`

Comment: @HBMCS: what about `.filter(personrole__title__contains="Principal investigator")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `obj` parameter:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=PersonRole)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_PI(self):  # 🖘 no obj
        return [p.person for p in self.person.all()]
```

This will however introduce an *N+1 problem*, you thus probably should boost efficiency with:

```
class ProjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [PersonFilter, FunderFilter]
    list_display = ('title', 'get_PI')
    ordering = ('title',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('person')
```

As fo filtering, you can use:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    def get_PI(self):
        return [
            p
            for p in self.person.filter(
                personrole__title__contains='Principal investigator'
            )
        ]
```

This will however slow down again the querying, since now we again perform one query *per* record.

Comment: Lovely, thank you. How can I filter by persons whose person_role__contains "Principal investigator"? Something like `return [p for p in self.person.filter(PersonRole.person_role__contains="Principal investigator")]` doesn't seem to work.